# Select max query returning all the rows in a table in Apache Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hive-query

I am querying my data using this query

> SELECT date_col,max(rate) FROM crypto group by date_col ;

I am expecting a single row but it is returning all the rows in the table. What is the mistake in this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get one row per `date_col` because you're grouping by it. If you just want the maximum `rate` then just do `SELECT max(rate) FROM crypto;`.

If you want to get the `date_col` for that record too then:

```sql
SELECT 
  date_col,
  rate
FROM crypto
WHERE rate = (SELECT MAX(rate) FROM crypto)
```

Comment: No, I want corresponding date with it as well.

Comment: Then you'll need to do one query to get the `max(rate)` and then a second to get the `date_col` for the given `max(rate)`. I have updated the answer.